Pip install package
I install a Python package in cmd or terminal, but it is not in the interpreter settings, why?
I have to go to the interpreter settings in Pycharm itself to install it. In that case, it will be shown in my packages.

You are probably using two different Python interpreters. In the cmd (or terminal) you probably install with one Python interpreter and from within Pycharm it is a different Python interpreter that is being used. And of course it can be that in one or more of those cases a Python virtual environment is in use.

As @sinoroc mentioned, you may be using two different python interpreters or maybe a virtual env of python is in use. You can edit/select the interpreter in PyCharm to reference the same that is being used in your cmd or create a virtual env in PyCharm terminal and install decencies there.
I normally would try to create a virtual env for my python project in PyCharm and install the dependencies/packages required. Hope this helps.
